# Convert the json result from http source connector

Tags: http, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have used the http source connector to get the data and publish the record into kafka "testdata" topic. I have the following config for a connect job,

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d ' {
"name": "https-connector",
"config": {
       "connector.class": "com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.HttpSourceConnector",
       "tasks.max": 1,
       "http.request.headers": "Accept:application/json",
       "http.request.url": "*********************",
       "kafka.topic": "testdata"
 }
```

}'

The http API result is,

```
{"fields":[
   {"id":"displayName","type":"text","name":"Display name"},
   {"id":"firstName","type":"text","name":"First name"}
  ],
"employees":[
   {"id":"4","displayName":"Charlotte Abbott","firstName":"Charlotte"},
   {"id":"5","displayName":"Ashley Adams","firstName":"Ashley"}
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the following output in the kafka topic. It has some binary string in the starting and ending of the message(start : r, end : H**5ee9b388-2063-3c78-b30a-05f2292ec7bf**�����^). "**5ee9b388-2063-3c78-b30a-05f2292ec7bf**" is the key of the message.

```
r{"fields":[{"id":"displayName","type":"text","name":"Display name"},{"id":"firstName","type":"text","name":"First name"}],"employees":[{"id":"4","displayName":"Charlotte Abbott","firstName":"Charlotte"},{"id":"5","displayName":"Ashley Adams","firstName":"Ashley"}]}H5ee9b388-2063-3c78-b30a-05f2292ec7bf�����^
```

I would like to get this as separate message in kafka,

```
{"id":"4","displayName":"Charlotte Abbott","firstName":"Charlotte"}
{"id":"5","displayName":"Ashley Adams","firstName":"Ashley"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It has some binary string in the starting and ending of the message

If you are using StringConverter or JSONConverter, then that shouldn't happen unless the API you're using is actually returning that.

> would like to get this as separate message in kafka

Kafka Connect API generally cannot split messages. The Connector sends one API response to one message; you need to use a secondary stream processor to split the array into individual records